# How to prevent Powerpoint from creating an empty title after deletion

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, title

I have little hope on this one but it's worth asking. When using Powerpoint, many times I delete the last field (say, last bullet point field; or last title field). Powerpoint then automatically creates a new, empty field; with the words "Click to add title" or "Click to add text".

These are very annoying to me, sometimes I just deleted the title because I want to paste another title or I actually don't want a title on that specific slide (i.e., if it's a full-screen figure). Then I have to go and delete the empty title again. I know it doesn't show in the presentation, but my it gets on my OCD and I need to delete it.

Is there a setting or checkbox that prevents this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

When you delete the contents of a text-box, it basically becomes
invisible. PowerPoint is just (over)trying to be helpful so you don't
lose sight of it.

If you intend to delete the text-box, don't bother deleting its text.
Click instead on its *frame*, to select the entire box, then press
<kbd>Del</kbd> to delete it.
Or you may click anywhere in the text-box while holding the
<kbd>Shift</kbd> key to select the box itself.

Note that you only get these prompts for text-boxes that PowerPoint
creates for you in new slides for default title and text.
You will not get them for your inserted text-boxes, which will disappear
once you delete their last character and move the cursor to another
object (older PowerPoint versions left such ghost boxes in the slide).

Comment: What harrymc said. But it might be simpler yet to base new slides on a layout that's appropriate for what you want to do; full frame images?  Start the slide based on the blank layout. It'll have no click-here boxes to delete.

Comment: Ah, one other addition to harrymc's reply:  sometimes it's hard to click directly on the outline of a text box; another option is to click anywhere within the text then press ESC (which selects the text's parent text shape) and then press DEL.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, you can also hold shift when clicking in a shape, that way you don't have to aim for the border.

Comment: @JackStoneS: I didn't know that, so added it to my answer. Thanks, this will be useful.

Comment: OCD notwithstanding, it might be better, at least in some cases, NOT to delete  the slide title placeholder, but add some appropriate text to it then move it off the top of the slide. That way if you need to create links from one slide to another (e.g. in an interactive presentation), you can identify the slide to link to by its title text rather than "Slide 42" or whatever.